# install jar file using maven installer plugin

Tags: java, maven, jar

i want to install a jar file using maven installer plugin.  when i run the command,  maven is adding the path of the command prompt to the path of the jar file. my cmd path is  **c:\doc** and the path i specified is **c:\jars\x.jar**, the error is the file **c:\doc\ c:\jars\x.jar** not found.

Comment: The exact command that you are trying to run or a more detailed description of the process may help us better understand the problem

Comment: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\jars\x.jar -DgroupId=org.custom 
    -DartifactId=x -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar

Comment: some question said that there is a similar problem solved by putting "", i have used "" with no result

Comment: That worked flawlessly on my PC with maven 3, even though I had no x.jar. Try using the verbose flag to debug the issue `mvn -X install:install-file...`

Comment: I have tried that but i got the same error.

Comment: Can you add the full log to your description using http://pastebin.com/ or any other service you feel comfortable with?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39779/discussion-between-grove-and-mohammed-falha)